# Download file based from user search using php

Tags: php, html, file, download

I have files like pdf in a directory and i have created a search form where in the user will input the filecode and it will search the source directory if it matches a filename it will allow the user to download the file, if not it will show "No Results" Here's what i did, but I am not sure what code should I use to download a file from my source directory, I just saw the code for downloading a file somewhere and substitute the source file with the variable i use when a user search

```
<html>
          <head>
            <title>Search  Contacts</title>
          </head>
          <body>

            <h3>Search Client File</h3>
            <form  method="post" action="#"  id="searchform">
              Type the File Code:<br><br>
                  <input  type="text" name="fcode">
            <br>
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
            </form>

<?php
$filecode=$_POST["fcode"];
     if (!empty($filecode))
     {
 $ch = curl_init();
$source = "/sdir/$filecode.pdf"; //this is from another computer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "/tdir/afile.pdf"; //this is from a different computer
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
     }
     else
     {
       echo "No Results";
     }

        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is that the downloaded file is unviewable

Comment: uh, why are you doing a curl request to the local file system? That's just... ludicrous.pretty much ALL of that code could be replaced with `copy($source, $destination)`.

Comment: does this still work if the source directory is on another computer, and the destination is on another computer?

Comment: no. but you're not specifying a foreign source or destination in the above code.

Comment: Im sorry, Now i have indicated, is there another code for something like that?